# Identification of a fitting which will hold a small rod

Tags: fitting, terminology

I need a fitting that screws in on both sides like a pillow block, is made of plastic and will receive a rod of 1/4" diameter. In other words the rod would just snap into the fitting and be held there.

I am pretty sure these exist, but I don't know what they are called so I need the right terminology to search for them.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what the rod is, how it will be used, what orientation it will be in and  describe what the end goal is, it may help to answer or provide alternatives. "*snap into the fitting and be held there*"  ??

Comment: please draw a picture